# Fetch and Display All folders and files present in my firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have created 3 folders in my firebase storage X, Y, and Z. Each of them contains PDF files and Powerpoint slides and images too.

Now, I want to fetch this data from firebase but I want to implement this such that the user gets an option to choose the folder X, Y, or Z. Another Option Can be all 3 folders get displayed (Just like in a file explorer) and the user can navigate. (All this needs to be done in an Android app)

Either of the work will work for me!

I know that fetching images or any other file and then displaying it using lisView or RecyclerView is possible. But I am unsure about folders present in firebase storage.

Now I am new to firebase and don't know much.
Help me out regarding how to implement this and if it isn't possible then please do suggest an alternative option.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (and my app), as my app adds files to Firebase Storage I get the `downloadUrl()` and other meta data (user who uploaded it, date & time, other details about the "file upload event" such as what screen or data object they were visiting when the uploaded the file, etc) and store all of that in a database such as RTDB or Firestore.

Then the user is able to search and display information from the database instead of me trying to pull directory & file info out of Storage.  This provides me flexibility in terms of grouping information, sorting, etc. that is identical to any other type of information.

In this way, I am treating Firebase Storage solely for file storage & retrieval.  I use Firestore (or RTDB) for data storage, query, sort/filter and retrieval.

Comment: What I am looking is this kind of functionality [link](https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/wGFEYBHtK-JzLMF1DVvxkw6h21LiLZ8op8ihvHykTg0N75O1I2yo3UTc4keNT-qMKclU=w1536-h754-rw)

Comment: how to do that using firebase? Consider me a noob but I am passionate about what I am doing so any sort of help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check out listAll() in these docs ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files ) or consider the pagination depending on the amount of files you expect.

You get a list of files with a prefix, so you could populate your view using that.